# Multithreading implementation itself in C

Tags: c, multithreading, implementation

I am a beginner C/C++ programmer first of all, but I am curious about it.
My question is more theoretical.

I heard that C does not have explicit multithreading (MT) support, however there are libraries which implement this. I found "process.h" header which has to be included for building MT programs, but the thing I don't understand is how the MT itself works.

I know there are threads in CPU (assume it's single core for simplicity) running and there is only one thread per moment. The CPU is switching between threads really fast so that user sees it as a simultaneous work (correct me if not).

But - what really happens when I write the following

```
beginthread( Thread, 0, NULL ) //or whatever function/class method we use
```

keeping in mind that C does not have MT support. I mean, **how does code tell the PC to run two functions multithreaded while it is not possible by the language explicit methods?** I guess there is some "cheat" inside library related to "process.h", but what is that cheat, I can't just find on the web.
To be more specific - I am not asking about how to use MT, but how is it build?

Sorry if was answered earlier, or question is too complicated :)

**UPD:**
Imagine we have C language. It has functions, variables, pointers etc. I dont know any  "special" function type that can run concurrently with other. Unless there are calls to some other functions from it. But then the caller function stops and waits?
Is it so that when I run MT applications, there is a special "global" function that calls my f1() and f2() repeatedly which looks like they were simultaneously working?

Comment: C *does* have explicit multithreading support, just `#include <thread.h>`.

Comment: Threading is not part of the processor. It's a concept pertaining to the operating system's scheduler. Multithreading involves interacting with the scheduler.

Comment: @KerrekSB What compiler, that supports thread.h, are you using?

Comment: Kerrek SB, yes I understand you mean the OS is dealing with processor threads, so my code does not directly communicate with CPU, but still what is the trick, that is what I don't get.

Comment: @this: I wasn't using any compiler. I was commenting on C :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB, C has `threads.h` (note the 's') since C 2011.  MT support is not part of the prior C standards, especially C99, which is (still) the most prevalent one in use, the availability of a newer one notwithstanding.

Comment: @KerrekSB Oh you meant <threads.h>.

Comment: @Elldissin: To be clear: A processor (i.e. a piece of hardware) does not have any concept of a "thread". Threads are a particular abstraction in the organizational structure of an operating system modeling a "schedulable unit" if you will.

Comment: @this: Yes, sorry, e.g. [see here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread).

Comment: @Eldissin, the answer is implementation-specific, and in all cases I know about it involves invoking features of the underlying operating system.  There is no "cheat" for this purpose inside any header file.  The magic happens in the implementation code, but exactly what form it takes varies.

Comment: The basic nature of the magic consists of the ability to save the current state (in practice, register values, page tables, etc.) of an executing task and swap that state out for another one.

Comment: Note that nothing in the C11 threads API requires asynchronous preemption, so it's completely possible for an implementation to do thread switching cooperatively as part of the synchronization functions and stdio functions. If implemented that way, the only state that needs to be saved/restored is the same as what `setjmp`/`longjmp` have to save/restore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, C11 does actually add multithreading support to the standard, so the premise that C does not support multithreading is no longer entirely correct.

However, I'm assuming your question is more to do with how can multithreading be implemented by a C library when standard C does(/did) not provide the necessary tools. The answer lies in the word “standard” – compilers and platforms can provide additional functionality beyond that required by the standard. Using such extra features makes the program/library less portable (i.e., more is required than is specified in the C standard), but the language and function call semantics can still be C.

Perhaps it is helpful to consider a standard library function such as `fopen` – somewhere inside that function code must eventually be called which could not be written in standard C, i.e., the implementation of the standard library itself must also rely on platform-specific code to access operating system functionality such as the file system. Every implementation of the standard library must thus implement the non-portable parts in a way specific to that platform (this is kind of the point of having a standard library instead of all code being platform-specific). But likewise a multithreading library can be implemented with non-standard features provided by that platform, but using such a library makes the code portable only to the platforms for which the same (or compatible) multithreading library is available.

As for how multithreading itself works, it is certainly outside the scope of what can be answered here, but as a simplified conceptual model on a single processor core, you can imagine the operating system managing “concurrent” processes by running one process for a short time, interrupting it, saving its state (current instruction, registers, etc), loading the saved state of another process, and repeating this. This gives the illusion of concurrent execution though in actual fact it is switching rapidly between different processes. On multi-core systems the execution on different cores can actually be concurrent, but there are typically more processes than there are cores, so this kind of switching will still happen on individual cores. Things are further complicated by processes waiting for something (I/O, another process, a timer, etc). Perhaps it suffice to say that the scheduler is a piece of software managing all of this inside the operating system and the multithreading library communicates with it.

(Note that there are many different ways to implement multithreading and multitasking, and statements in the above paragraph do not apply to all of them.)

Comment: The example with `fopen` is useful, I think I understand more now, but some things not clear yet.

Comment: The last paragraph of your answer seems just what I was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's platform specific. On Windows it eventually goes down to `NtCreateThread` which uses the assembly instruction `syscall` to call the operating system. So you can qualify it as a cheat.

On Linux it's the same, just the function with the syscall is called `clone` instead.

Comment: That looks promising, so the syscall is some call to OS service, which makes my app run in MT mode? Does OS have some kind of "infinite loop" - a handler which then can switch between my two functions, feeding them to processor?

Comment: @elldissin: the os interrupts the normal code every so often using what is called a clock interrupt. When enough time is elapsed it looks in its list of threads and runs the next minding priorities. The syscall is just for adding to that list.

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand it, enough for my level of knowledge at least :)